# How to print the preceding line in unix which is filtered using grep -v -l "pattern"

Tags: unix, grep

I have a file with content as below :

```
label1 name
1
label2 id
2 
label3 id
0
```

I am using grep to scan through the lines and resulting a failure if lines not matching pattern"label" has a value of greater than 0

```
if (grep -v -l "label" fileA) > 0
then
    echo -e "failure"
else
    echo -e "success"
fi
```

I also want to print those lines corresponding to value which is failed (i.e. >0)

```
label1 name
label2 id
```

I tried below, but it gives no result. I am not sure, where exactly i am doing wrong

```
ps -ef | grep -v -l "label" fileA > 0
```

I am new to Unix, and trying to figure out how to print the failure lines.

Please help

Comment: Are you aware that `> 0` redirects to a file named `0`?

Comment: Oops ! yes. i just saw that its re-directing the output to file. I am not sure on how to print that. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$ cat f
label1 name
1
label2 id
2
label3 id
0
$ awk '/label/ {k=$0;getline tmp;print k,tmp}' f
label1 name 1
label2 id 2
label3 id 0
```

You can filter the value as per your need like below -

```
$ awk '/label/ {k=$0;getline tmp;if(tmp > 0) {print k,tmp}}' f
label1 name 1
label2 id 2
```

> Edit 1: If your file has some lable without value -

```
$ cat f
label1 name
1
label2 id
2
label3 id
0
label4 id

label5 id
10
$ awk '/label/ {k=$0;getline tmp;if(tmp > 0) {print k,tmp}}' f
label1 name 1
label2 id 2
label5 id 10
```

Comment: this prints all the lines, instead of failure lines
`label1 name 1`
`label2 id 2`
`label3 id 0` BTW, i also have lines with no values at all. Will this impact the output of awk ?

Comment: @user1023627 - 2nd cmd `awk '/label/ {k=$0;getline tmp;if(tmp > 0) {print k,tmp}}' f` will print only those value which has value `>0` and if your file has some lable without value then it will work as expected, check my updated answer for detail. Comment here if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the exit status of `grep` is 0 if selected lines are found and 1 otherwise. I think you were lookong for `grep -c` :

```
$ grep -c "label" f
3
$ echo $?
0
```

So you can do something like

```
if [ $(grep -c "label" f) -gt 0 ]; then
   echo match found
fi
```

or

```
grep -c "label" f
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   echo match found
fi
```

You also want to print the lines found. You can store these in a variable.

```
foundlabels=$(grep "label" f)
echo "You can test on \$? here, but now you have another way."
if [ -n "${foundlabels}" ]; then
   echo "failure"
   echo "${foundlabels}"
else
  echo "success"
fi
```